# Grocery CRUD auto id with prefix

Tags: codeigniter, unique, prefix, grocery-crud

i want to ask
is there any simplest way to make prefix like A001,A002,A003 
when inserted to database with grocery CRUD ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use the callback_before_insert (See [here](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/callback_before_insert)) and then write a callback function to prepend the relevant field value with your A001, A002 etc. The field values will be in the $post_array array so for instance you would:

```
function prepend_callback($post_array) {
 $post_array['my_field'] =  'A001' . $post_array['my_field'];
 $post_array['my_other_field'] =  'A002' . $post_array['my_other_field'];
 return $post_array;
}
```